# Problema con variable global en Android

Tags: android, variables

Variables_HassMovil

```
public class Variables_HassMovil{
private static Variables_HassMovil instance;

private String cuenta,calibre,nombrecalibre,fechamostrar;

private Variables_HassMovil(){}

public void setCuenta(String Cuenta){
    this.cuenta=Cuenta;
}
public String getCuenta(){
    return this.cuenta;
}

public String getCalibre() {
    return calibre;
}

public void setCalibre(String calibre) {
    this.calibre = calibre;
}

public String getNombrecalibre() {
    return nombrecalibre;
}

public void setNombrecalibre(String nombrecalibre) {
    this.nombrecalibre = nombrecalibre;
}

public String getFechamostrar() {
    return fechamostrar;
}

public void setFechamostrar(String fechamostrar) {
    this.fechamostrar = fechamostrar;
}

public static synchronized  Variables_HassMovil getInstance(){
    if (instance==null){
        instance=new Variables_HassMovil();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

}

VariablesOpcion_HassMovil

```
public class VariablesOpcion_HassMovil extends Application {

private String cuenta=null;
private String calibre=null;
private String calibrenombre=null;
private String fechamostrar=null;



public String getCalibre() {
    return calibre;
}

public void setCalibre(String calibre) {
    this.calibre = calibre;
}

public String getCalibrenombre() {
    return calibrenombre;
}

public void setCalibrenombre(String calibrenombre) {
    this.calibrenombre = calibrenombre;
}

public String getCuenta(){
    return this.cuenta;
}

public void setCuenta(String Cuenta){
    this.cuenta=Cuenta;
}

public String getFechamostrar() {
    return fechamostrar;
}

public void setFechamostrar(String fechamostrar) {
    this.fechamostrar = fechamostrar;
}
```

}

Quiero simplificar la siguiente parte:

```
VariablesOpcion_HassMovil variables = (VariablesOpcion_HassMovil) getApplication();
 Log.d("VARIABLE", variables.getFechamostrar());
```

Como puedo inicializarla desde el Oncreate porque no me deja me marca error.No es como poner `TextView x;` y poder utilizarlo para toda el activity, como lo hago?

Comment: Quieres accederla desde onCreate pero esa clase extiende de application, que deseas realizar con esa variable?

Answer (score 1):

Si es una variable global, la tenés que declarar como estática.

Vas a tu clase `Application` o `Activity` principal, declaras las variables como `static`, por ejemplo:

```
public static Variables_HassMovil misVariables;
```

... y después podés acceder desde cualquier lado a esa información de la siguiente manera.

```
ActivityMain.misVariables.getblablabla();
```